# CCM Boost PFC avg rms current

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, power-factor-correction, calculation

I follow the "Fundamentals of Power Electronics-3rd Edition" to derive the below equation.
Now, I would like to derive the Transistor Average, [image]
， and I follow the book formula, but my answer is different from the book's answer, could someone tell me where I do wrong?

[image]

Book description,

[image]
[image]

Below is my calculation process.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Average current seen by the MOSFET of a PFC boost converter, is the double integrale of one switching period and the main supply frequency.

What has been detailed in the book is the RMS current calculation in which a Reimann Integral approximation is used.

This is not needed for the average current as depicted below.
I get the same results as yours.

Tm is the main's period.
Iin is the rectified current (ie inductor current)
[image]

Comment: There may be numbers not "migrated" from the 2nd edition: "The table for PFC rectifier circuits on page 909, under the boost circuit of the first line, has erroneous expressions carried over from the second edition. The CCM Boost Transistor Average expression should contain a 4 instead of an 8, and for the diode rms expression, an 8 instead of a 16. Otherwise, the boost form factor of
κ = rms/avg for equal input and output voltages is κ = 0.711 < 1, whereas the rms always exceeds the average and as always, κ ≥ 1."